# How to resolve problem with delete button with Excel VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    
    ' Check if any cell in column A is modified
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
        ' Set the range from the modified cell in column A to column D
        Set rng = Range(Target, Cells(Target.Row, "D"))
        
        ' Remove existing borders if the corresponding cell is empty
        If IsEmpty(Target) Then
            rng.Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
        Else
            ' Add new borders to each cell
            For Each cell In rng
                With cell.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Weight = xlThin
                End With
                With cell.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Weight = xlThin
                End With
                With cell.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Weight = xlThin
                End With
                With cell.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Weight = xlThin
                End With
            Next cell
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I want that even if I delete the value of more than one cell at once, the border should be removed automatically.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is not clear what your problem/question is. Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question. Maybe this link will help you too: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Instead of using `IsEmpty(Target)`, move your loop `For Each cell` outside the `If` and use `IsEmpty(cell)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following structure as a template, replacing the commented line with relevant code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim targetrange As Range, targetcell As Range
    Set targetrange = Intersect(Target, Range("A:A"))
    
     If Not targetrange Is Nothing Then
    
        For Each targetcell In targetrange
        
            '.. do something with targetcell
        
        Next

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

With the following code you can paste several values at the same time and also delete several cells at once. During pasting, some cells may gain value and others may lose value...

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim ir As Range, ar As Range, cell As Range
   Dim allEmpty As Range, allValue As Range
   ' Check if any cell in column A is modified
   Set ir = Intersect(Target, Range("A:A"))
   If Not ir Is Nothing Then
      ' Something changed... make two ranges one with all empty cells
      ' and one of cells with value
      For Each cell In ir
         If cell.Value2 = vbNullString Then
            If allEmpty Is Nothing Then
               Set allEmpty = cell
            Else
               Set allEmpty = Union(allEmpty, cell)
            End If
         Else
            If allValue Is Nothing Then
               Set allValue = cell
            Else
               Set allValue = Union(allValue, cell)
            End If
         End If
      Next
      'I loop through the Areas and not the cells
      ' of empty and filled cells
      If Not allEmpty Is Nothing Then
         For Each ar In allEmpty.Areas
            ar.Resize(ar.rows.CountLarge, 4).Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
         Next
      End If
      If Not allValue Is Nothing Then
         For Each ar In allValue.Areas
            With ar.Resize(ar.rows.CountLarge, 4).Borders
               .LineStyle = xlContinuous
               .Weight = xlThin
            End With
         Next
      End If
   End If
End Sub
```